# my jquery ajax form submit doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I have the following javascript that's using ajax with jquery to submit a form.

```
$(function() {
    $("#signform").submit(function() {
        alert();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "page/sign.php",
            data: { mail: $("#inputEmail").val(), 
                    pass: $("#inputPassword").val(),
                    nick: $("#inputNick").val(),    
                    date: $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', new Date()) },
            sucsess: handler,
            error: function(err) { alert('error: ' + err.status) }
        });
    });

    function handler(var){
        $('#message').html(val);
    }
});
```

and html code is here, using bootstrap !

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="signform">

// ... something codes

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-offset-2 col-lg-10" align="center">
      **<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>** &nbsp;
      <a href="index.php"><button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button></a>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

When I pressed the submit button, it went to the index page.

I don't know what is wrong.

js code is in the same page in sign.php

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: also whether the alert is popped up when the submit button is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not preventing the default action of the submit button, you can either call [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), or return false from the submit handler to fix this

Also in the `handler` method the parameter was called `var` which is invalid

```
$(function() {

    $(document).on('submit', "#signform", function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "page/sign.php",
            data: { 
                mail: $("#inputEmail").val(), 
                pass: $("#inputPassword").val(),
                nick: $("#inputNick").val(),    
                date: $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', new Date()) 
            },
            success: handler,
            error: function(err) { 
                alert('error: ' + err.status) 
            }

        });
        return false; //this will prevent the default action and will stop the event propagation
        //if you do not want to stop event propagation you can use
        //e.preventDefault();
    });

    function handler(val){ //also invalid variable name var here
        $('#message').html(val);

    }
});
```

Comment: I think there are another reason... for test, when i include **alert method**. it wasn't work. that php page loaded through innerHTML. like this
{    var str = xhr.responseText;
                var personDiv = document.getElementById("Content");
                personDiv.innerHTML = str;}
maybe it makes some trouble

Comment: There is a typo. You wrote `sucsess` instead of `success`.

Comment: @ArunPJohny sorry for late and noob. it means, in index.php content div, i insert string that sign php page. i need to change frame? architect? ;(

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will help you better, Here U=page URL, F=Page method,D=Data

U=sign.php,

F=page,

D="mail: '+$("#inputEmail").val()+',pass: '+$("#inputPassword").val()+',nick: '+$("#inputNick").val()+',date: '+$.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', new Date())+'"

```
// function for call page method using ajax


     function Operation(U, F, D) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: U + '/' + F,
            data: D,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (r) {
                var str = r.d;
        });
    }
```